# AHK - # (windows) hotkey stay in pressed state at first use

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote a simple script wich open the active joomla site administrator page in Firefox:

```
#a::
    Send, !d
    GetText(url)
    StringGetPos, localHost, url, localhost
    startPos := 7
    if(localhost)
        startPos := 17
    StringGetPos, pos, url, /,,startPos
    adminURL := SubStr(url,1,pos)
    Send ^t%adminURL%/administrator{enter}
return

GetText(ByRef txt)  ;copy the selected text to clipboard
{
    BlockInput, on
    prevClipboard = %clipboard%
    clipboard =
    Send, ^c
    BlockInput, off
    ClipWait, 2
    txt = %clipboard%
    txt:=RegExReplace(txt,"\x20{2,}"," ")
    clipboard = %prevClipboard%
}
```

At first use (after reboot) the script do weird things:

- logout
- open command line
- open Windows Explorer

It looks like the windows key is still in pressed state when I send the input.
After first use the script work properly.
I think something is wrong with the getText function.

I try a lot of modification, but doesn't work.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please describe what your script is supposed to do in detail. Specifically, provide the contents of `url` and describe how the resulting `adminURL` is supposed to look like. Anyway, have you tried using `#a UP::`, triggering the hotkey upon release?

Comment: I would also split up the `Send ^t%adminURL%/administrator{enter}` line. Like this `Send, ^t` `Sleep, 200` `SendInput,%adminURL%/administrator{enter}`. Directly before the Send Command you should also check if Firefox is the active window.

Comment: @MCL `#a UP::` solution is working, but has a side effect, it's activate the native windows button function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the hotkey label wait until you have released each key:

```
#a::
    KeyWait, LWin ; or RWin, as desired
    KeyWait, a ; just to make sure nothing interferes
    /*
        do stuff!
    */
return
```

In contrast to `#a UP::`, this won't let a <kbd>[image: WIN]</kbd> key press trickle through when releasing <kbd>A</kbd> first.